# Setting up Vapor and Clang in the same project

Tags: swift, xcode, makefile, llvm-clang, vapor

My project is based on Vapor.

The aim is to use libclang, build a wrapper on top of it in C language. Then, make this library available from swift.

How can I mix the two? Preferably still building my project from XCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build C modules in Swift Package Manager fairly easily, [see here](http://ankit.im/swift/2016/04/06/compiling-and-interpolating-C-using-swift-package-manager/) for more information.

To wrap a system C library, see instructions [here](https://oleb.net/blog/2017/12/importing-c-library-into-swift/)